# Clojure open a large txt file edit the data and write it to a new file

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to open a file that is to large to slurp. I want to then edit the file to remove all characters except numbers. Then write the data to a new file.

So far I have
 `(:require [clojure.java.io :as io])`

```
(:require [clojure.string :as str])

:jvm-opts ["-Xmx2G"]

(with-open [rdr (io/reader "/Myfile.txt")
            wrt (io/writer "/Myfile2.txt")]
  (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
    (.write wrt (str line "\n"))))
```

Which reads and writes but I'm unsure of the best way to go about editing.Any help is much appreciated. I'm very new to the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just need to modify the `line` value before writing it. If you want to modify a string to remove all non-numeric characters, a regular expression is a pretty easy route. You could make a function to do this:

```
(defn numbers-only [s]
  (clojure.string/replace s #"[^\d]" ""))
(numbers-only "this is 4 words")
=> "4"
```

Then use that function in your example:

```
(str (numbers-only line) "\n")
```

Alternatively, you could `map` `numbers-only` over the output of `line-seq`, and because both `map` and `line-seq` are lazy you'll get the same lazy/on-demand behavior:

```
(map numbers-only (line-seq rdr))
```

And then your `doseq` would stay the same. I would probably opt for this approach as it keeps your "stream" processing together, and your imperative/side-effect loop is only concerned with writing its inputs.

Comment: @J.Titor since this answer solved your problem, please accept it